# OpenCV vs Labview Images Greyscale (U16) - Difference in values

Tags: python, opencv, labview, grayscale

I am trying to understand why LabView shows one set of values for an image, while OpenCV shows another set of values.

I have two U16 Grayscale PNG images that I am trying to combine vertically to create one continuous image. The majority of the pixels are near zero or low-valued, with the ROI having pixel values in the middle of the U16 range. In Python, this is achieve by reading the file using OpenCV, combining the image using numpy and then using Matplotlib to display the values:

```py
image_one = cv2.imread("..\filename_one.png", cv2.IMREAD_UNCHANGED)
image_two = cv2.imread("..\filename_two.png", cv2.IMREAD_UNCHANGED)
 
combined_image = numpy.concatenate((image_one, image_two), axis=0)
 
plt.figure(figsize=(15, 15), dpi=18) plt.imshow(combined_image,
cmap="gray", vmin=0, vmax=65535) //Sliced to show the ROI
```

**Dual Exposure Image**
[image: Dual Exposure Image]

As seen above, this show the image as have two different dynamic ranges, resulting in different exposures. To normalize the images, we can try to rescale it to take advantage of the same dynamic range.

```py
rescaled_one = ((image_one - image_one.min()) / (image_one.max() -
image_one.min())) * 65535 rescaled_two = ((image_two -
image_two.min()) / (image_two.max() - image_two.min())) * 65535 

combined_rescaled = numpy.concatenate((rescaled_one, rescaled_two),
axis=0)
 
plt.figure(figsize=(15, 15), dpi=18) plt.imshow(combined_irescaled,
cmap="gray", vmin=0, vmax=65535) //Sliced to show the ROI
```

**Rescaled Image - Dual Exposure**
[image: Rescaled Image - Dual Exposure]

This still shows the same issue with the images.

In LabView, to combine images vertically, I adapted a VI that was published to stitch Images horizontally:
https://forums.ni.com/t5/Example-Code/Stitch-Images-Together-in-LabVIEW-with-Vision-Development-Module/ta-p/3531092?profile.language=en

The Final VI Block Diagram looks as follows:

**VI Block Diagram - Vertically Combine Images using IMAQ**
[image: VI Block Diagram - Vertically Combine Images using IMAQ]

The Output you see on the Front Panel:

**Singular continuous Image - Front Panel**
[image: Singular continuous Image - Front Panel]

The dual exposure issues appears to have disappeared and the image now appears as a single continuous image. This didn't make any sense to me, so I plotted the results using Plotly as follows:

```py
fig = plty.subplots.make_subplots(1, 1, horizontal_spacing=0.05)
fig.append_trace(go.Histogram(x=image_one.ravel(), name="cv2_top",
showlegend=True, nbinsx = 13107), 1, 1)
fig.append_trace(go.Histogram(x=image_two.ravel(), name="cv2_bottom",
showlegend=True, nbinsx = 13107), 1, 1)
fig.append_trace(go.Histogram(x=lv_joined[:1024, :].ravel(),
name="LabView_joined_top", showlegend=True, nbinsx = 13107), 1, 1)
//First Image 
fig.append_trace(go.Histogram(x=lv_joined[1024:,:].ravel(), name="LabView_joined_bottom", showlegend=True, nbinsx =
13107), 1, 1) //Second Image fig.update_layout(height=800) fig.show()
```

**Histogram - Python vs Labview respective halves - Focus on Low
pixels**
[image: Histogram - Python vs Labview respective halves - Focus on Low pixels]

Here it shows that the Second Image's pixel values have been "compressed" to find the same distribution as the the First Image. I don't understand why this is the case. Have I configured something wrong in LabView or have I not considered something when reading in a file with OpenCV?

Original Images:

[image: image_one] [image: image_two] [image: labview_joined]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Please refer to the answer posted here: [https://forums.ni.com/t5/LabVIEW/OpenCV-vs-Labview-Images-Greyscale-U16-Difference-in-values/td-p/4172150/highlight/false]